# How to remove email addresses and phone number from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I need to remove all email and phone number from string in PHP. 
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Show the code ............

Comment: from which string and what is your effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just for a start up not a complete answer. You need to read more about regular expressions and its usage.

remove email addresses :

```
$pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/";
$replacement = "[removed]";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303234/2179864)

For phone numbers :

```
$text = preg_replace('/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/', '[removed]', $text);
```

this looks for:

a plus symbol (optional), followed by a number, followed by between 4-20 numbers, brackets, dashes or spaces, followed by a number

and replaces with the string [removed].

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764902/2179864)

Comment: that wont match all legit email addresses. ditto for the phone numbers

Comment: yes. I was editing post.to add the same

Comment: + rather than * maybe?

Comment: Email removal is working fine but phone number removal is not working. I am getting this error:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 16

Comment: @ankitsuthar you may need to escape the hyphen by putting a \ in front of it - eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377374/laravel-preg-replace-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class