# laravel preg_replace Compilation failed: invalid range in character class

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

Please take a look at blew error and my code.Something Am I missing anything?

call stack

```
in /app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php line 217
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 13', '/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php', '217', array('string' => 'gegegeg', 'separator' => '-'))
at preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\s-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]/u', '', 'gegegeg') in Controller.php line 217
at Controller->make_slug('gegegeg') in AdsController.php line 153
at AdsController->FormAds('14', '71', '97', object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdsController), 'FormAds'), array('main_id' => '14', 'sub_id' => '71', 'typ_id' => '97', object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
```

Code

```
 echo preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_-s-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]/u', '', 'gegegeg');
```

Error:

> preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class
>   at offset 13

Best Regards

Comment: Move the `-` to the beginning or end of the character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape hyphens now, so just add one after your `\s`

'/[^a-z0-9_\-\s\-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]/u'

See this answer [preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764212/preg-match-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class-at-offset)

And see your regex working here https://3v4l.org/9qni7